# How to authenticate into SharePoint online on-premise server

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, forms-authentication, sharepoint-on-prem

Recently I configured SharePoint online on-premise server. I am trying to perform REST API to fetch lists from SharePoint. For that I need to authenticate into SharePoint server. But it throws "404 Not found" on form-based authentication. Before that I am able to authenticate into SharePoint trial version, but using the same source code online on-premise server fails to authenticate.

These are my authentication steps

1. Get security token using `POST: login.microsoftonline.com/rst2.srf`
2. Get access token using security token from previous request by using `POST: mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0`
3. Get form digest value using access token from previous request: `POST: mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/contextInfo`

The URL `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0` throws "404 Not found error". Why I am getting this error?

Is there any change should I need to support to get successful authentication into SharePoint online on-premise server?

**For more details:**

> SharePoint trial account: mydomain.sharepoint.com
>
> username:user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
>
> password: password
>
> ---
>
> SharePoint online on-premise account: mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev
>
> username: user@mydoamin.com
>
> password: password

Comment: my apologies, what do you mean with "SharePoint online on-premise", do you mean SharePoint Hybrid Architectures? http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/04/sharepoint-hybrid-architectures-introduction/

Comment: Its an online account but user is not in active directory, that is user name is ending with "onmicrosoft.com".